# IR Receiver Remote Controller for Windows

Tags: ir, remote-control, windows

My dad watches netflix on his pc with his wireless mouse, hes gotten older and cannot hit the volume slide well enough.

I have an arduino kit (ard nano), an IR recevier and remote controller laying around (all from the arduino kit).

I want to use the remote control when you press volume down on it to make the windows volume go down.
I tried using chatgpt but have gotten nowhere, what would be the best simplest solution for this.

I was thinking it would be an easy read-in of the data from the receiver but how would you transfer this data on to windows? Is this possible, I havent found many examples online

Thank you all :)

Comment: Are there some keyboard commands that you can enter on the PC instead of manipulating a scroll bar with the mouse ? If so, state what they are here and/or check yourself if an Arduino Leonardo or Arduino Micro (both ATMega32U4 based) is capable of issuing such commands.

Comment: get a wireless keyboard that has volume buttons ... remove the electronics and place them in a small box ... discard the keyboard matrix ...  add a couple of buttons, and connect them in place of the keyboard matrix ... you can use a scrap keyboard for this, since the buttons are not needed

Answer (score 1):

There are USB / HID keyboard codes for volume.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2) we see volume up is 0x80 and volume down is 0x81.

Consider obtaining an Arduino board which is capable of supporting a USB / HID port so that you can easily emulate a keyboard.  It would be best to choose a board with hardware USB / HID support.  But it may be possible to emulate (limited?) USB / HID support using software only.

There are plenty of Arduino USB / HID project ([here](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Make-a-Arduino-HID-Keyboard/) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-essentials/circuitpython-hid-keyboard-and-mouse) are just 2 examples).  This should get you started designing an Arduino sketch which can transmit a keyboard's volume up and down control codes into one of the computer's USB ports.

And there are plenty of Arduino ASK / IR receiver projects ([here](https://www.instructables.com/Using-an-IR-Receiver-With-Arduino/) and [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/blogs/2021/how-to-send-and-receive-data-over-ir-signals-with-an-arduino) are just 2 examples).  As there are many IR remote control codes, this part of the project might take a bit of research to uncover the codes used in the IR remote control you posses.